# How to get customers age from MySQL Date

Tags: mysql

```
birthday
------------
1988-10-09
1919-12-12
```

How to calculate the age properly and rounded?

I have this:

```
SELECT
ROUND((TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(birthday)) / 365)
FROM customer
```

Is there something more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) AS age
FROM customer
```

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html)

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f81f9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datediff()` function to get day count between two dates. Flooring the result gives you the integer part of the age.

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),birthday) / 365) as customer_age
FROM costumer
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another options:

```
 SELECT ROUND(DATE_DIFF(NOW(), birthday) / 365) AS age FROM customer
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful for you

```
select DATEDIFF(customer.dob, '2013-10-01') / 365.25 as age

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(customer.dob,'2013-10-01')), ‘%Y’)+0 AS age
```